# Logstash upstart script

Tags: ubuntu, logstash, upstart

Trying to add logsatash to upstart in ubuntu 14.04. The script is very simple:

```
  # logstash - agent instance
  description     "logstash"

  start on virtual-filesystems
  stop on runlevel [06]

  limit nofile 65550 65550

  script
     /usr/bin/java -jar /home/user/logstash/logstash-1.2.1-flatjar.jar agent -f /home/user/logstash/logstash.config -l /home/user/logstash/new1.log -v
  end script
```

The command itself (the line inside the script stanza )works and starts logstash when running it from the shell but when starting is using :

```
start logsatsh
```

logstash starts. but after a few minutes it stops and the service status is: (using the status command)

```
logstash stop/waiting
```

The logstash file config file:

```
input {


     stdin{}
        file{
                path => "/home/user/log/logstash-1.4.0/mylog.log"
        }
         udp {
                codec => json
                host => "0.0.0.0" # string (optional), default: "0.0.0.0"
                #message_format => ... # string (optional)
                port =>  9998
                #tags => ... # array (optional)
                type => "log4j" # string (required)
       }
        tcp{
                port => 9998
                type => "log4j"
                codec => json
        }
}

output {
  stdout{}
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

The logstash log file:

```
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:16.300]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Living Lightning] version[0.90.3], pid[1850], build[5c38d60/2013-08-06T13:18:31Z]
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:16.301]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Living Lightning] initializing ...
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:16.308]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.plugins: [Living Lightning] loaded [], sites []
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:20.300]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Living Lightning] initialized
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:20.300]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Living Lightning] starting ...
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:20.420]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.transport: [Living Lightning] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/100.91.222.96:9300]}
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:23.473]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.cluster.service: [Living Lightning] new_master [Living Lightning][P9fRLWzCQmaXuRKLZkUNig][inet[/100.91.222.96:9300]], reason: zen-$
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:23.773]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.discovery: [Living Lightning] elasticsearch/P9fRLWzCQmaXuRKLZkUNig
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:23.806]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.http: [Living Lightning] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/100.91.222.96:9200]}
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:23.807]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Living Lightning] started
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:23.927]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.gateway: [Living Lightning] recovered [4] indices into cluster_state
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:23.970]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Sefton, Amanda] version[0.90.3], pid[1850], build[5c38d60/2013-08-06T13:18:31Z]
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:23.975]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Sefton, Amanda] initializing ...
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:23.975]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.plugins: [Sefton, Amanda] loaded [], sites []
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:25.013]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Sefton, Amanda] initialized
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:25.013]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Sefton, Amanda] starting ...
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:25.102]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.transport: [Sefton, Amanda] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/100.91.222.96:9301]}
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:28.311]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.cluster.service: [Living Lightning] added {[Sefton, Amanda][EAiYOR8jSO-DZEDJlaSYng][inet[/100.91.222.96:9301]]{client=true, data=f$
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:28.350]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.cluster.service: [Sefton, Amanda] detected_master [Living Lightning][P9fRLWzCQmaXuRKLZkUNig][inet[/100.91.222.96:9300]], added {[L$
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:28.361]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.discovery: [Sefton, Amanda] elasticsearch/EAiYOR8jSO-DZEDJlaSYng
log4j, [2014-04-25T13:50:28.362]  INFO: org.elasticsearch.node: [Sefton, Amanda] started
{:timestamp=>"2014-04-25T13:50:15.148000+0000", :message=>"Plugin is finished", :plugin=>, :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2014-04-25T13:50:15.138000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline started", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2014-04-25T13:50:15.959000+0000", :message=>"Starting embedded ElasticSearch local node.", :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2014-04-25T13:50:23.944000+0000", :message=>"New ElasticSearch output", :cluster=>nil, :host=>"localhost", :port=>"9300-9400", :embedded=>true, :level=>:info}
{:timestamp=>"2014-04-25T13:50:28.388000+0000", :message=>"Plugin is finished", :plugin=>"ruby", message=>"%{+yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ} %{host}: $
{:timestamp=>"2014-04-25T13:50:28.390000+0000", :message=>"Plugin is finished", :plugin=>"logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}", port=>"9300-9400", embedded_htt$
{:timestamp=>"2014-04-25T13:50:28.402000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline shutdown complete.", :level=>:info}
```

No fork is done by the logstash process(tested with strace).
Tried changing the command part to 'exec' with no success. Any idea?

Comment: What does your logstash config file look like?

Comment: @Alcanzar , I have edited my question, added the config file ant idea?

Comment: That stdin might be the issue.

Comment: Also is there a reason you aren't using the most recent version of logstash?

Comment: @Alcanzar you were right the problem was the  stdin that can't be config when using upstart add it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

i'd suggest you to look for upstart logstash.conf available on elasticsearch debs,
this is the part you might want to look:

```
console none
script
  # Defaults
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin
  LS_HOME=/var/lib/logstash
  LS_HEAP_SIZE="500m"
  LS_JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.io.tmpdir=${LS_HOME}"
  LS_LOG_FILE=/var/log/logstash/logstash.log
  LS_USE_GC_LOGGING=""
  LS_CONF_DIR=/etc/logstash/conf.d
  LS_OPEN_FILES=16384
  LS_NICE=19
  LS_OPTS=""

  # Override our defaults with user defaults:
  [ -f /etc/default/logstash ] && . /etc/default/logstash

  HOME="${HOME:-$LS_HOME}"
  JAVA_OPTS="${LS_JAVA_OPTS}"
  # Reset filehandle limit
  ulimit -n ${LS_OPEN_FILES}
  cd "${LS_HOME}"

  # Export variables
  export PATH HOME JAVA_OPTS LS_HEAP_SIZE LS_JAVA_OPTS LS_USE_GC_LOGGING
  test -n "${JAVACMD}" && export JAVACMD

  exec nice -n ${LS_NICE} /opt/logstash/bin/logstash agent -f "${LS_CONF_DIR}" -l "${LS_LOG_FILE}" ${LS_OPTS}
end script
```